# Python Selenium closing a pop-up window

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like to close this window opened up on Amazon web site by using Selenium with Python. I've tried `find_element_by_xpath`, but it doesn't work. Here's the snippet of the code;

```
close_to_list = browser.get("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]")
```

I get the xpath of that '**X**' button but I guess I need to close it as `switch_to_alert`, but I'm new to this era so I couldn't write it properly.

Here's the image view;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxTRj.png)

[image]

Comment: Please attach the relevant HTML and describe the outcome of your code. Did you add the `.click()` in `driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath').click()`?

Comment: `broswer.get()` is used to nagivate to a URL. You probably want one of the methods to [locate elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `switch_to_alert()` as well as `get()` to close modal window. Just try to close it with below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Close"]'))).click()
```

This allows you to wait for button appearance and click the button

Comment: Button is already clickable. It is 'Add to List' button on Amazon. Maybe this makes it clearer for you to imagine the scenario. Your answer seemed to work but I realized that it doesn't close the pop-up, it closed the whole automated-browser so I unchecked the right answer button.

Comment: *closed the whole automated-browser*... Are you sure? My code should click on `X` button on modal... Do you need to handle that button or "Add to List button?"

Comment: I succeeded to press to 'Add To List' button and after that new pop-up window opened, I need to close it by already-seen 'X' button

Comment: *already-seen 'X' button*... Already seen for you or for WebDriver? :) Did you try my code or not? You should add `WebDriverWait...` line after you clicked on "Add to List" button

Comment: @SelinElibol , So? Can you share your current state?