# How to click the close button within a modal window through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Cannot click button `id="close` in modal window.

Trying all xpaths like:

```
//button[@data-dismiss='modal']
//button[@id='close'], //button[@type='button']
//button[contains(.,'Закрыть')]
//button[contains(@data-dismiss,'modal')]
//button[contains(@id,'close')]
```

Also trying to combine xpaths, but still not working

Code:

```
<div id="idCardGroupChangeStatusResult" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog st-modal-dialog" style="width: 600px; padding-top: 250px;">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header st-pad-normal">
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="modal-footer">
<button id="close" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"> Закрыть </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Css not working to

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Selenium closing a pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083499/python-selenium-closing-a-pop-up-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `element_to_be_clickable` not works, try code below to check if there's more than one close buttons on the page. You can use code below to filter by visible or visible and latest one and click on it.

```
close_buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idCardGroupChangeStatusResult #close")))
# check how many buttons in on the HTML, you can try "visibility_of_all_elements_located"
print(len(close_buttons))

visible_buttons = [close_button for close_button in close_buttons if close_button.is_displayed()]
visible_buttons_len = len(visible_buttons)
print(visible_buttons_len)

visible_buttons[visible_buttons_len - 1].click()
```

Does the message disappears?

Update, message window disappear:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

#...

status_message = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idCardGroupChangeStatusResult")))

actions.move_to_element(status_message).perform()
# here you can get text from message window, check/assert ..
status_message.find_element_by_css_selector("#close").click()
```

Comment: Thx you for answer! It disappears then i run my tesn in debug mode step by step, but if i run it returns - E       IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Odiosuu share `print(len(closeButtons))` result printed in console

Comment: @Odiosuu when you manually hover on message window does it disappear or stay until you unhover?

Comment: stay until i hover it

Comment: Still got selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

..\..\..\venv1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:80: TimeoutException. u try to use time.sleep(5) but it not helps. test fails before i got that modal windows

Comment: What do you do before message status, click button? Do you use something to wait until page loading complete?

Comment: Up wait to 20sec, and looks like works! I test it and update status, thx!

Comment: Yes, i got another modal windows with buttons "confirm" and "cancel". After click "confirm" i have to wait this modal window.

Answer (score 3):

As the element with text as **Закрыть** is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) so to locate the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-default.btn-sm#close[data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-sm' and @id='close'][@data-dismiss='modal']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thx for answer! Trying this way, timeout exception. also trying this one -     el = self.xpath('//*[@aria-hidden="false"]')
        el2 = el.xpath('//div[@class="modal-dialog st-modal-dialog"]')
        el3 = el2.xpath('//div[@class="modal-footer"]')
        el4 = el3.xpath("//button[@id='close']")
        el4.click() this "step by step" way not working too

Comment: Where are you getting all these `el.xpath('//div[@class="modal-dialog st-modal-dialog"]')` and ` el3.xpath("//button[@id='close']")` from? Can you just copy, paste and execute the line of code and update me the status please?

Comment: With Xpath: ..\..\..\venv1\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py:80: TimeoutException. With css same